# How do I perform a conditional check in a double loop efficiently?

Tags: java, oop, java-8, break

I didn't really know how to formulate the title of this question, so I'll just jump into an example.

Let's say that I want to iterate over a list of elements, and based on certain conditions, add said element to a new list.

Here I create a method that basically wants to check if an item is exclusive to the first list (isn't present in the second one). Now I know that for this particular silly example you could solve this using sets, but I'm just trying to illustrate a case where something like this would pop up

```
public List<Item> newItems(List<Item> items, List<Item> otherItems) {
    List<Item> newItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Item i: items) {
        for (Item j: otherItems) {
            if (i.equals(j))
                //Missing code
        }
        newItems.add(i);
    }

    return newItems;
}
```

So here I only want to add the current `Item i` to `newItems` if it is not equal to a single item in `otherItems`. My first impulse was to put `break;` where it says `//Missing Code`, but that would only break out of the first loop and not impede the adding of `i` to `newItems`.

I am aware of a correct solution where you would use a boolean variable to consistently check the truth of the if statement, and then add `Item i` to `newItems` based on it's truth value at the end of the second loop. It would look something like this:

```
for (Item i: items) {
    boolean check = true;

    for (Item j: otherItems) {
        if (i.equals(j))
            check = false;
            break; //To avoid unnecessary iterations
    }

    if (check)
        newItems.add(i);
}
```

This seems incredibly bulky and also quite redundant however. Is there a more efficient and elegant way of doing this?

Comment: @AchmadJP it's an ArrayList, so each element has a distinct position in the list, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to create a list, where are collected items from `items` excluding items that are present in both `items` and `otherItems`. If yes, you can do it simply by [`List#removeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-):

```
public List<Item> newItems(List<Item> items, List<Item> otherItems) {
    List<Item> res = new ArrayList<>(items);  // create a copy of items
    res.removeAll(otherItems);                // remove items presented in otherItems
    return res;
}
```

If there are other condition(s) to exclude items, use a stream, filter(s) and collector, as follows:

```
return items.stream()
            .filter(i -> !otherItems.contains(i))
            .filter( /* another condition */ )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: In this example that is indeed what I was doing, but I was just looking for a general way to perform an action based on certain conditions. The solution you propose is just relevant to this example

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [Wakachopo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36455934/2711488) and [AchmadJP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36455910/2711488), you can do what you describe using `contains` or `binarySearch`. Now that you say, these operations are only exemplary and you might have different conditions—well nothing stops you from using the same pattern, but now you may have to write the particular method yourself:

```
for(Item i: items) {
    if(!hasMatchingCondition(i, otherItems) {
        newItems.add(i);
    }
}

static boolean hasMatchingCondition(Item i, List<Item> list) {
    for(Item j: list) {
        if(whatever condition regarding i and j) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Clean and short-circuiting.

You can do the same in a single method using labeled statements, i.e

```
outer: for(Item i: items) {
    for(Item j: list) {
        if(whatever condition regarding i and j) {
            continue outer;
        }
    }
    newItems.add(i);
}
```

but labeled statements are considered a discouraged feature by some developers and perhaps more important, you may find another use for the `hasMatchingCondition` method somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, if the List is already sorted. The faster solution I think is using binary search as it is faster than sequential search.

```
for( Item i: items){
    if(Collections.binarySearch(otherItems, i) < 0){
        newItems.add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have to, I would do this way:

```
for(Item i: items){
    if(!otherItems.contains(i)){
        newItems.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but can `.contains` be used on an ArrayList? I thought that was only valid syntax on Sets

Comment: You can see in official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

In this and other cases I think you could give them an upside down focus and assume that all items fulfill your conditions and then remove those which not. For this example:

```
public List<Item> newItems(List<Item> items, List<Item> otherItems) {
 List<Item> newItems = new ArrayList<>(items);

 for (Item i: items) {
     for (Item j: otherItems) {
         if (i.equals(j)){
             newItems.remove(i)
             break;
     }
 }
 return newItems;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the nested loop, in Java 8 you can use the [Streams API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) to do the following:

```
public List<Item> newItems(List<Item> items, List<Item> otherItems) {
    return items.stream()
              .filter(i -> !otherItems.contains(i))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can do something like;

```
CollectionUtils.removeAll(collection1, collections2);
```

This method returns a collection to you as well.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html